# Filter results with JSON Decode

Tags: php, json

I have an url that gives me this result:

```
{"status":"ok","result":[{"account":"11754-101","name":"test","channels":"15","billing":"1","billingstep":"60","increment":"0","credit":"1.0089"},{"account":"11754-102","name":"mult","channels":"15","billing":"1","billingstep":"60","increment":"0","credit":"2.7835"}]}
```

I'm trying to get the "credit" value of just one account to view it.

```
Account: 11754-102
Credit: XXX
```

The code I did is this, but it seems to be broken:

```
<?php
$json = '{"status":"ok","result":[{"account":"11754-101","name":"test","channels":"15","billing":"1","billingstep":"60","increment":"0","credit":"1.0089"},{"account":"11754-102","name":"mult","channels":"15","billing":"1","billingstep":"60","increment":"0","credit":"2.7835"}]}';

$apiResult = json_decode($json, true);
($apiResult['status'] !== 'ok') && 
  trigger_error('Unexpected API Result');

empty(($account = array_filter($apiResult['result'], function($item) {
  return $item['account'] === '11754-102';
}))) && trigger_error('Account not found.');

echo $account[0]['credit'];
?>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Blank and white page

Comment: It would be an undefined offset error @Greedo, based on my test.

Answer (score 2):

Not a huge fan of using the shortcuts you are using when a simple `if()` would do, but the main problem is that when you get to the end, you use

```
echo $account[0]['credit'];
```

If you look at the output of your `array_filter()`, in this case you end up with...

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [account] => 11754-102
            [name] => mult
            [channels] => 15
            [billing] => 1
            [billingstep] => 60
            [increment] => 0
            [credit] => 2.7835
        )

)
```

So although it only has one element, it is element 1 and not 0.

I've rewritten the code to take that into accounf (and added some `if`s)...

```
$json = '{"status":"ok","result":[{"account":"11754-101","name":"test","channels":"15","billing":"1","billingstep":"60","increment":"0","credit":"1.0089"},{"account":"11754-102","name":"mult","channels":"15","billing":"1","billingstep":"60","increment":"0","credit":"2.7835"}]}';

$accountToFind = '11754-102';

$apiResult = json_decode($json, true);
if ($apiResult['status'] !== 'ok')  {
    trigger_error('Unexpected API Result');
}

$account = array_filter($apiResult['result'], 
    // Pass the account to find into the function rather than hardcode it.
    function($item) use ($accountToFind) {
        return $item['account'] === $accountToFind;
});

if ( !empty($account) ) {
    // If there is anything left, extract the first one
    $account = array_shift($account);
    echo $account['credit'];
}
else {
    trigger_error('Account not found.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know if you got an error message, if you want to display errors, you can use this article to do so: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?answertab=votes#tab-top)

The problem is that `$account[0]` doesn't exist, `$account["result"][0]` does exist. So the code would be echo `$account['result'][0]['credit'];`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your corrected code. You can achieve the same using array_pop. Your account was at offset 1 but you were fetching at 0.

```
<?php
$json = '{"status":"ok","result":[{"account":"11754-101","name":"test","channels":"15","billing":"1","billingstep":"60","increment":"0","credit":"1.0089"},{"account":"11754-102","name":"mult","channels":"15","billing":"1","billingstep":"60","increment":"0","credit":"2.7835"}]}';

$apiResult = json_decode($json, true);
($apiResult['status'] !== 'ok') &&
trigger_error('Unexpected API Result');

empty(($account = array_filter($apiResult['result'], function($item) {
    return $item['account'] === '11754-102';
}))) && trigger_error('Account not found.');

echo array_pop( $account )['credit'];
?>
```